# WP_Query Order by Specific Post ID First

Tags: wp-query, loop, order

I'm creating a website where I have a need to show a set of posts from a custom loop but I need to display a specific post first.

This post will be dynamically specified in the URI by a $_GET variables. Basically, if that $_GET variable is set, it will contain the ID of the post that I need to display first. I need to somehow modify my custom query to show this post first, then carry on with the rest of the query ordering by date.

Having looked at the WP docs, I can't see a way to do this and my Googling has failed me.

My query is set up as follows:

```
$review_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'surgeonreviews',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => $meta_key,
    'orderby' => $sortby,
    'order' => $order,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'month' => $_GET['review-month'],
            'year' => $_GET['review-year']
        )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'LESC_SurgeonId',
            'value' => $post_meta['LES_SurgeonId'][0]
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'LESC_Rating',
            'value' => $_GET['rating'],
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    )
);
```

Is there any way to achieve this?